# Push array content into empty array using another variable as a placeholder for the content array name

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

**EDIT: @Andreas got the solution. Thank you all for the replies! You all rock!**

I'm trying to list and array but I get all sorts of weird errors.
venueValue = garden and personRange = a so locationArray = garden a, but when I use it inside the each function it doesnt work. If I use gardena instead of location array inside the each function it works perfectly fine.

```
gardena = ["Private Villa - Gozo", "Palazzo Parisio", "Ta' Frenc - Gozo", "Mridiana Wine Estate"];
    locationArray = new Array();
    locationArray = venueValue+personRange;
    $.each(locationArray, function(index, value) {
        alert(value);
    });
```

I bet the solution is obvious but I;m completely lost here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If `gardena` is global: `locationArray = window[venueValue+personRange]` - but why don't you just use `gardena` directly?

Comment: I get venueValue from a form and personRange from another form. gardena only exist as an array in my js file(soon to be a db table).EDIT: It worked. I was sure it was obvious. Thanks a lot, thsi project got me exhausted.

Comment: What is `venueValue+personRange`?  You assign the result of that addition to the name `locationArray`.  If that addition isn't an array then you can't iterate through it with $.each().

Comment: venueValue+personRange is the name of the array, but only the name not the value. As I said sorry for asking an obvious question(tough I'm stuck here for about 3 hours now).

Comment: But if gardena is not global (I might use this later). Thank you in advance.

Comment: So `venueValue+personRange` is the string *"gardena"*?

Comment: None of this is making a lot of sense. Please provide explanation of what you expect this code to do. You have an empty array and 2 string variables and another array `gardena`. Current explanation is also very vague

Comment: @WingmanImd Try the UPDATE in my answer. Hope you are expecting that only.

Comment: All these comments indicate that the question is not clear. You should [edit] any additional info into the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

To add an element to an array, you should use the push() method. Doing like you are doing it sets locationArray to a string or a number.

I also recommend defining arrays like so

```
var array = [];
```

instead of new Array();

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Push your values like the below code snippets. So that you can iterate your values using `$.each()` method.

```js
var locationArray = [],venueValue = 'garden ',personRange = 'a';
locationArray.push(venueValue,personRange); //Push your values here in an array
$.each(locationArray, function(index, value) {
    alert(value);
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE:**

I think I got your point. Use `eval` function like this. It will capture the values of `gardena` variable. Then you can iterate with that.

```js
var locationArray = [],venueValue = 'garden',personRange = 'a',
    gardena = ["Private Villa - Gozo", "Palazzo Parisio", "Ta' Frenc - Gozo", "Mridiana Wine Estate"];
locationArray = venueValue+personRange;
$.each(eval(locationArray), function(index, value) {
    alert(value);
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

DEMO in [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/u8h9swfc/)

Answer (score 0):

what is happening when you are using + sign to concatenating Array it will concatenate last element of  venueValue to personRange.

So let say my a array is a=[1,2,3] and b is b=[6,7,8] if i will try c=a+b it will give result [1,2,36,7,8] which is not desirable so merging of two array can be done by concatenation

ex: c=a.concat(b);

it will give result [1,2,3,6,7,8]

and if you want result like [16,27,38] you can use this function

```
function ab(a,b)
{var c=[]; 
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{c[i]=a[i]+''+b[i];} 
return (c);
} 
var a=[1,5,6]; 
var b=[9,0,8]; 
console.log(ab(a,b));
```

and If you want like

```
var a='ab'; 
var k='b'; 
var abb=[1,2,3,4]; 
var c=eval(a+k); 
console.log(c);
```

it this case we are adding the strings and evaluated them

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to say that `venueValue` is the string *"garden"* and `personRange` is the string *"a"*, such that `venueValue+personRange` is the string *"gardena"*, and that you want to iterate through the values of the array `gardena`.

If this is accurate, then here is my recommendation: first, put the array in an object rather than making it a global.

```
var mystuff = {
        gardena : ["Private Villa - Gozo", "Palazzo Parisio", "Ta' Frenc - Gozo", "Mridiana Wine Estate"],
        };
```

Then you can get the array from the object:

```
var locationArray = mystuff[ venueValue+personRange ];
$.each(locationArray, function(index, value) {
    alert(value);
});
```